# How to re-size the d3 or c3 graph which resides in a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, c3.js

I have multiple dialog's with selected axis graphs from same source. so, i added a re-size function to all the graphs. when i opened a single graph re-size works. if i opened multiple dialog's with graphs, it only re-sizes the last opened dialog not the previous dialog's.
Thanks.

Comment: Some code or, better yet a fiddle would be most helpful.

Comment: <div id="lineDialog"></div>